# Read multiline XML value using XSL and JS

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I faced a problem with handling  multiline XML value in XSL file.
For example, I have a following part of XML:

```
<book>
    <id>1</id>
    <content>qwerty
             asdfg
             zxcvb
    </content>
 </book>
```

I am trying to get value of node `<content>` using XSL functional and write it to HTML table cell but it doesn't work.

Following JS code i am using to get necessary cell in my table and write there a multiline value:

```
document.getElementById("row1").getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML = "<xsl:value-of select="book/content"/>";
```

With single line value it works fine. I believe that innerHTML property can't read multiline values. Are there any other opportunities to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: So which browsers do you need the Javascript to work with, which XSLT processor do you use? Modern Javascript allows multiline strings, for older ones you would need to escape line breaks which is kind of complicated however in XSLT 1.

Comment: I use only IE and XSLT 1.0. The problem is content of xml nodes may be different. It can be singleline or multiline value, so i can't do line breaks specifically for constant value from example in this question

Comment: Don't tell us it doesn't work, tell us how it fails. Is the problem that the data is displayed without newlines? If so, that's because HTML renders newlines as spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need IE support then

```
document.getElementById("row1").getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML = `<xsl:value-of select="book/content"/>`;
```

should work.

On the other hand, if you only target IE then you can exploit that is XSLT processor is a version of MSXML that supports calling into JScript where you can then use the JScript `replace` method to escape line breaks in strings as needed for J(ava)Script as `\n`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:user="http://example.com/user-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl user"
    version="1.0">

    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
        function escapeLineBreaks(input) {
          if (typeof input != 'string') {
            input = input.item(0).text;
          }
          return input.replace(/\n/g, '\\n').replace(/\r/g, '\\r');
        }
    </msxsl:script>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr id="row1">
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <script>
                    document.getElementById('row1').cells[1].innerHTML = "<xsl:value-of select="user:escapeLineBreaks(book/content)"/>";
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There i am using IE only

Comment: Are you running the XSLT inside IE or on the server?

Comment: I just run XML file through IE. XML links to XSLT

Comment: If you use the XSLT code in the browser to create the HTML then of course it seems easier not to use script at all to populate that `td` element but rather to do it directly with XSLT. We would need to see more of the context of the XSLT and HTML it generates to help with that approach.

Comment: i tried your method using escapeLineBreaks function. It works fine, but multiline values writes in one line in "td" element. Is it really to fix?

Comment: Well, that is how HTML works, no? If you want line breaks in HTML to be rendered as line breaks then use CSS e.g. `<td style="white-space: pre;"></td>` on the `td` element or use a `pre` element inside the `td`.